# Draw a overlaying rectangle (example)

Tags: c#, drawing

How would I go about drawing a rectangle like this image?
(Notice rectangle slight grey in the middle)
[Screenshot](http://puu.sh/1niK2)

I've got drawing Rectangles on Forms/PictureBox's ect but for the of me can't figure out how to do it over all your open applications.

Any feedback will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about doing this on a webpage?  If so, you should add the HTML and CSS tags and maybe add ASP.NET, but remove C#.  Not really a C# issue in that case.

Comment: Over the users screen at any point. As if you want to select an area to capture a screenshot.

Comment: Applications I've used for this take the screenshot, then present it in full screen to the user who can then select it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want just a border you can use  [ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe.aspx).

Comment: I believe that's what "rubber band selection" rectangles use. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314945

Comment: Nice link. I believe that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a window that is set to the size of the display.  No border, no background.  Basically, an *invisible* window.  Then you can draw rectangles or whatever else you want and they will appear to be overlaid on top of other things.

Keep in mind you cannot keep this window open all the time as it will cover up everything else and prevent events from getting through.  Open it as needed and then close it.